# Find a transformation to a random variable X from Uniform(0, 1) with SymPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

Is it possible to find the transformation expression to X from U(0, 1) in SymPy?

```
import sympy.stats as stat
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')
p = sp.Piecewise( (x + 1, (-1. <= x) & (x <= 0)), (1 - x, (x >= 0) & (x <=1 )), (0, True) )

X = stat.ContinuousRV(x, p, Interval(-1, 1))
cdf = stat.cdf(X)(x)

# Where to go from here?
stat.sample(X)
# TypeError: object of type 'ConditionSet' has no len()
```

sample in sympy/stats/crv.py

```
def sample(self):
    172         """ A random realization from the distribution """
--> 173         icdf = self._inverse_cdf_expression()
    174         return icdf(random.uniform(0, 1))
```

How can I find the inverse cdf expression from the custom piecewise?
By hand I get: 1 - sqrt(2-2u)

Is it possible with another library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that cdf is a nested Piecewise object. These should be folded with `piecewise_fold`. (Aside: your formula for `p` has a floating point number `1.`, I replaced it by `1` to make SymPy's life easier.)

```
cdf = sp.piecewise_fold(cdf)
u = sp.Symbol('u', positive=True)
inv = sp.solveset(cdf - u, x, domain=sp.Interval(0, 1))
```

Now `inv` is

```
Intersection(Interval.Ropen(0, 1), {-sqrt(2)*sqrt(-u + 1) + 1, sqrt(2)*sqrt(-u + 1) + 1})
```

It's unfortunate that SymPy did not discard the second solution, which is obviously outside of the interval `(0, 1)`. But at least the first one is correct.

You still can't use this for `stat.sample`, so any sampling would have to be coded directly. Two remarks aside:

SymPy is not a particularly effective tool for sampling, as it is a numerical task. In NumPy, sampling this specific (triangular) distribution is a one-liner:

```
>>> np.random.triangular(-1, 0, 1, size=(5,))
array([-0.40718329,  0.26692739,  0.84414925,  0.33518136, -0.7323011 ])
```

SymPy also has [Triangular](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html#sympy.stats.Triangular) built in, not that it helps with sampling.

Comment: Changing 1. back to int 1... piecewise_fold still returns a nested piecewise. The same code is yelding: Union(ConditionSet(x, Eq(-2*u + x**2 + 2*x + 1, 0), Interval(-1, 0)), ConditionSet(x, Eq(-2*u - x**2 + 2*x + 1, 0), Interval.Lopen(0, 1)))

Comment: I'm using SymPy 1.2. If your version is older, consider upgrading, as the handling of piecewise was improved recently.

Comment: Was using 1.1... 1.2 fixed the issue